# "List interface provides two methods to efficiently insert and remove multiple elements" - Does anyone know what the second method is?

Tags: java, collections

From the Java docs I see the "**The List interface provides two methods to efficiently insert and remove multiple elements at an arbitrary point in the list.**". Presumably

1. ***addAll​(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)***
   What's the second method?

Or is this in reference to ***removeAll​(Collection<?> c)*** and ***addAll​(Collection<? extends E> c)?***

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html

Comment: What are you asking? The answer to your question is right there, **in** your question.

Comment: I'd have thought my question was clear enough. Added the rest of the API excerpt am trying to understand. Hopefully that helps. Happy to clarify further.

Comment: The docs refer to two methods, you list those exact two methods, and are asking what methods the docs refer to. Again, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: No. removeAll​(Collection<?> c) and addAll​(Collection<? extends E> c) are defined in the collection interface that List inherits from. I believe in this case the API is referring to the index based: addAll​(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)  defined in the List interface and a second method which is what am trying to figure out.

Comment: Except that `addAll(int, Collection<? extends E> c)` is hardly "an arbitrary point in the list" which the docs mention. I believe the docs are simply reminding you that `List` includes those inherited methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a documentation bug. See [JDK-8215983](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215983).

As you noted, it's possible to insert multiple elements at an arbitrary point in the list by using `addAll(int, Collection)`. There's no corresponding *single* method to remove multiple elements starting at an arbitrary, particular point in the list. That can be accomplished via the `subList(from, to).clear()` method sequence.

The docs might be referring to the [`removeRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html#removeRange(int,int)) method, which is a *protected* method on `AbstractList`. That's intended for use by lists that are implemented using `AbstractList`, not for general users of the `List` interface. It might have been present in an earlier evolutions of the `List` interface, but the reference to it in the `List` documentation was never cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Stuart. Yes it doesn't even make sense to remove a collection from a certain point in the collection. I think removeRange would be a more pragmatic approach, not to mention the operation itself is more relevant to lists.

Comment: @simiyub the `removeRange` method is the backend of the `subList(from, to).clear()` operation mentioned in the answer. Implementers only need to deal with it when they have a more efficient solution than repeatedly calling `remove(int)`, so they should override that method then. Note that it is even possible to “remove a collection from a certain point” or range, using the same approach, i.e. `subList(from, to).removeAll(Collection)`. Even the existing `addAll(index, collection)` could written as `subList(index, index).addAll(collection)` instead.